# What happens to the product before the integral when substitution method?

Tags: integration, substitution

$$
\int_{r=0}^{r=3/\sqrt2} \int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=2\pi} \left(\sqrt{9-r^2}-r\right) r dr
$$

Then compute them to

$I_1 = 2\pi\int_{r=0}^{3/\sqrt2}\left(\sqrt{9-r^2}\right)rdr$ and $I_2$ which isn't relevant for this question.

When I then use the substitution method I would usually think I would use $u=9-r^2$ and get:

$$2\pi\int_{u=9}^{9/2}\sqrt u.du$$

But when I look In the solution it shows that it becomes

$$-\pi\int_{u=9}^{9/2} \sqrt u.du$$

Could someone explain why the $2\pi$ changes to $-\pi$?
Would be really appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please typeset your question with MathJaX, I got you started with the first one. Here is a [MathJaX tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Hope you stay around and contribute to the site.

Comment: okei, will do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$u = 9-r^2, du = -2r \,dr, dr = -\frac{1}{2r}du$

$\displaystyle \int_{r=0}^{r=3/\sqrt2} \int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=2\pi} \sqrt{9-r^2} \, r \, dr \, d\theta = -\pi \int_{9}^{9/2} \sqrt{u} \, du = \pi \int_{9/2}^{9} \sqrt{u} \, du$

Comment: Totally forgot that formula I see now... But thanks.